# MQTT client not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to publish messages using a button click event. The client is suppose to send `ON` and `OFF` payload. For some reason that I cannot fathom why this is not working.

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883')

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('publish', function (data) {
        client.publish(data.topic, data.payload);
        console.log('Publish to '+ data.payload);
    });
});
```

**client.js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

$('#button').ready(function () {
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.on('mqtt', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.topic + ' ' + msg.payload);

            $("#on").click('click', function () {
                socket.emit('publish', {topic: 'test/test', payload: 'ON'});
                console.log("on");
            });

            $("#off").click('click', function () {
                socket.emit('publish', {topic: 'test/test', payload: 'OFF'});
                console.log("off");
            })

        });
    })
})
```

**index.HTML**

```
<h1>Test MQTT</h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<div id="on" >
    <input type="submit" value="ON" >
    </div>

<div id="off">
    <input type="submit" value="OFF">
</div>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are the `#on` / `#off` event handlers working?

Comment: No they're not. Please what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you know what would trigger the `mqtt` event on the socket?

Comment: `socket.on('mqtt'` should tigger the event. Typically it should send the payload to `console.log`  on `server.js`

Comment: `socket.on('mqtt'` responds to the event, but it wouldn't trigger it.

Comment: I'm sure if I can get the click event to work. I should be fine. I think that's the problem i'm having.

Comment: I would move the event bindings out of the `socket.on` callbacks ... you can really just move them to the top level and they will start to work.

Comment: Please can you use jsfiddle to show your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Oh it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the event listeners `.click` will not actually fire until the callback for `socket.on('mqtt'` fires. This would be in response to an `'mqtt'` socket event. This event will not fire until the server publishes, but the server only publishes when the client emits -- this only  happens when you click a button. The event listeners cannot get added until the event they are supposed to trigger fires.

Rearrange your logic a bit:

```
$('#button').ready(function () {
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        $("#on").click('click', function () {
            socket.emit('publish', {topic: 'test/test', payload: 'ON'});
            console.log("on");
        });

        $("#off").click('click', function () {
            socket.emit('publish', {topic: 'test/test', payload: 'OFF'});
            console.log("off");
        });

        socket.on('mqtt', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.topic, msg.payload);
        });
    });
});
```